# BigQuery: How to calculate the running count of distinct visitors for each day and category?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery I have a table like this:

> startTime:STRING, visitorId:STRING, category:STRING

Example for this content:

```
startTime            visitorId   category
-------------------  ---------   --------
2013-11-27 00:00:00     A           X         
2013-11-27 05:00:00     A           X 
2013-11-27 07:00:00     B           X 
2013-11-28 08:00:00     C           X
```

I would like to have the following result:

```
day         category  runningCountOfDistinctVisitors  
---------   --------  ------------------------------   
2013-11-27     X                   2
2013-11-28     X                   3
```

I have tried the following query but it does not seems to work (it's been running for over 3 hours on 1.2M rows table and still hasn't finished) :

```
SELECT left(a.startTime,10) as day, 
a.category,
count(distinct a.visitorId) as runningCountOfDistinctVisitors
FROM [MyDataset.MyTable] a 
LEFT JOIN EACH [MyDataset.MyTable] b ON a.category = b.category 
WHERE left(b.startTime,10) < left(a.startTime,10)
GROUP EACH BY a.category, day
ORDER BY a.category, day
```

I also tried to work with the partition function but count distinct does not seems to be supported.

Comment: Note: I have a total of 3 queries that are currently marked as "Query Running" (including the query that I mentioned). These queries started a little more than 3 hours ago. The queries are all similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

ts:timestamp, visitor:string, category:string

```
ts                       visitor  category
-----------------------  -------  --------
2013-11-27 00:00:00 UTC  A        X  
2013-11-27 00:00:00 UTC  A        X  
2013-11-27 00:00:00 UTC  B        X  
2013-11-28 00:00:00 UTC  C        X  
2013-11-27 00:00:00 UTC  A        Y  
2013-11-28 00:00:00 UTC  B        Y  
2013-11-29 00:00:00 UTC  C        Y
```

query:

```
select 
  day, category, sum(cd) 
over
  (partition by category order by day) as running_total
from (select date(ts) as day, category, count(distinct visitor) as cd from
  [test.runningtotal] group by day, category)
```

this will produce:

```
day         category  running_total
----------  --------  -------------
2013-11-27  X         2  
2013-11-28  X         3  
2013-11-27  Y         1  
2013-11-28  Y         2  
2013-11-29  Y         3
```

I didn't test this on large dataset but it might be faster than the JOIN solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I have tried it but for some reason the result for the running_total is a little higher than what it should be (on my table). I will try to dig deeper to find out why.

Comment: count(distinct visitor) is approximation, try count(distinct visitor, xxx) where xxx is some high number, higher than the day/category group should have (see https://developers.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions for count)

Comment: I forgot to mention, yes I already tried to use the count distinct with the second(optional) parameter and it didn't work either. I will try to see if can put my table public with some data. Thanks again for your help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: This would not work if visitors are repeating across days for the same category.

Comment: yeah, I think this is wrong, it would double count the vistor A from one day and the next

Comment: actually, this just be solved by first grouping by category, visiting and min date the visitor appeared...

Answer (score 2):

COUNT DISTINCT is a calculation intensive operation (that's why BigQuery offers to do an approximated count after 1000, unless explicitly requested not to). Doing an almost CROSS JOIN is also an intensive operation. Mix both 2 with a large dataset, and you could be running into a computationally hard to solve problem.

Suggestions (as I don't have access to your data to play with):

- Instead of a COUNT DISTINCT, do a sub-query with a GROUP EACH. Then just COUNT that on an outer query. Same results, with a probably better computation distribution.
- Why LEFT JOIN EACH and not just JOIN EACH?

Update: I like Radek's answer, where he uses a COUNT() OVER() instead of a JOIN: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20346427/132438

Answer (score 1):

Realize I'm very late to this but it helped me iron out something I was working on, so I figured I'd add a bit more.

In BigQuery you can run a rolling count distinct on a dataset that widens with the window.

On this example it would look something like this.

```
`SELECT day, category, MAX(runningCountofDistinctVisitors) running_ct
FROM
(SELECT left(a.startTime,10) as day, 
a.category category,
count(distinct a.visitorId)
  OVER(PARTITION BY category
  ORDER BY LEFT(a.startTime,10)) as runningCountOfDistinctVisitors
FROM [MyDataset.MyTable] a 
LEFT JOIN EACH [MyDataset.MyTable] b ON a.category = b.category 
WHERE left(b.startTime,10) < left(a.startTime,10)
GROUP EACH BY a.category, day, a.visitorId)
GROUP EACH BY day, category
ORDER EACH BY day, category`
```

This solves the problem of the count being higher than you would expect it, because the window is widening to include the current day and all previous days, as opposed to summing the counts of the individual preceding days.

I believe there is also a way to do this without an outer query that gets the max each day, but I haven't been able to figure that out yet.

Comment: Order by is not really allowed if distinct is present. How are you doing this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567839/7131019

Answer (score 1):

Some of the previous answers don't really do count-distincts across days. They are just doing count-distincts by day, and then summing those day counts.

This set of queries will allow you to compute running-count-distincts on very large datasets.  I've tested it on billions of unique IDs.

It compresses large numbers of unique visitor ids into small sketches, one per day and category, that can be merged with other sketches to get unique counts quickly.

It uses TEMP TABLEs because they are much faster than CTEs or subqueries.

```
-- create one sketch per <day, category> pair
CREATE TEMP TABLE sketches AS
(SELECT
  category
, DATE(ts) day
, HLL_COUNT.INIT(visitor_id, 24) visitor_sketch
FROM [MyDataset.MyTable]
WHERE DATE(ts) >= DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP BY category, day
);

-- get a list of the days involved in the study
CREATE TEMP TABLE window_starts AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT(day) day
  FROM sketches
);

/* For each category and day in the study, merge all the 
   corresponding sketches for that category and from the
   beginning of the study up to that day.

   N.B. "MERGE" performs an approximate count distinct
   see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hll_functions#hll_countmerge
*/
SELECT
  category
, window_starts.day
, HLL_COUNT.MERGE(visitor_sketch) visitors
FROM window_starts
CROSS JOIN sketches
WHERE sketches.day <= window_starts.day
GROUP BY category, window_starts.day
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use

```
row_number() over (partition by visitor,category order by cast(ts as date)) as row_n
```

and then

```
sum(if(row_n=1,1,0)) over (partition by category order by cast(ts as date)
```