# Running count of apperance of customer id Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

there are similar questions on here but either I cannot figure out how to convert to my situation (Likely) or they are not that similar but read close to what i want to do ([BigQuery: How to calculate the running count of distinct visitors for each day and category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270669/bigquery-how-to-calculate-the-running-count-of-distinct-visitors-for-each-day-a))

Anyway...

I have an order table in bigquery that has many column headers which i will need to use all of them but i will just list a few of them here

orderID, customerID, transactionDate, Revenue

(I will need to get all of the fields)

I want to work out the instance of a customer ID in the table as a new column, so if i had place 3 orders, and my customer ID was 1234, the 1st instance in the data table would be 1 in a new column, the 2nd would be 2 and the 3rd would be 3

for example say my data looks like this

```
> OrderID     ||    CustomerID    ||    TransactionDate    ||    Revenue
> 1           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 2           ||    2             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 3           ||    3             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 4           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 5           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 6           ||    2             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20 
> 7           ||    4             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20
```

I would like to run a query against it the adds in a new column stating the instance if the CustomerID record so it would like like

```
> OrderID     ||    CustomerID    ||    TransactionDate    ||    Revenue ||Instance
> 1           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||1 
> 2           ||    2             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||1
> 3           ||    3             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||1 
> 4           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||2
> 5           ||    1             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||3 
> 6           ||    2             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||2 
> 7           ||    4             ||     01/01/15          ||     £20    ||1
```

Each time an already seen customerID happens the Instance increments 1

Also I need to run this against an ever growing table that is currently at 1.6 million rows.

I hope some one can help me out.

Cheers

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Window Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) are helping you here:

Window functions enable calculations on a specific partition, or "window", of a result set. Each window function expects an OVER clause that specifies the partition, in the following syntax:

```
OVER (
      [PARTITION BY <expr>]
      [ORDER BY <expr>]
      [ROWS <expr> | RANGE <expr>]
     )
```

`PARTITION BY` is always optional. `ORDER BY` is optional in some cases, but certain window functions, such as `rank()` or `dense_rank()`, require the clause.

`JOIN EACH` and `GROUP EACH BY` clauses can't be used on the output of window functions. To generate large query results when using window functions, you must use `PARTITION BY`.

```
select *,
row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by TransactionDate) as Instance
from  (select 1 as OrderID, 1 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 2 as OrderID, 2 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 3 as OrderID, 3 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 4 as OrderID, 1 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 5 as OrderID, 1 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 6 as OrderID, 2 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue), 
 (select 7 as OrderID, 4 as CustomerID, '01/01/15' as TransactionDate,'£20' as Revenue)
 order by OrderID
```

Returns:

```
+-----+---------+------------+-----------------+---------+----------+---+
| Row | OrderID | CustomerID | TransactionDate | Revenue | Instance |   |
+-----+---------+------------+-----------------+---------+----------+---+
|   1 |       1 |          1 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        1 |   |
|   2 |       2 |          2 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        1 |   |
|   3 |       3 |          3 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        1 |   |
|   4 |       4 |          1 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        2 |   |
|   5 |       5 |          1 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        3 |   |
|   6 |       6 |          2 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        2 |   |
|   7 |       7 |          4 | 01/01/15        | £20     |        1 |   |
+-----+---------+------------+-----------------+---------+----------+---+
```

Comment: Thank you so much, got me to the exact result I needed. I really appreciate your answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should use window function like row_number OVER (Partition by yourgroupbyfields order by transaction_date)