# BigQuery Window ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified

Tags: window-functions, google-bigquery

I'm investigating porting some bigquery legacy sql containing windowed distinct counts like this

`count(distinct brand_id) over (partition by user_id order by order_placed_at range between 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) as last_7_day_buyer_brands`

to Standard sql.... but I get this error....

`Window ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified`

For reference I've tried `APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT` function with no luck.

Is there a better way to get this to work other than write the subqueries and group by's?

Most of the other queries have ported to standard sql with only minor changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#aggregate-analytic-functions)

> OVER clause requirements:
>
> PARTITION BY: Optional.
> ORDER BY: Optional. **Disallowed if DISTINCT is present.**
> window_frame_clause: Optional. **Disallowed if DISTINCT is present**.

*note: above is 'highlighted' by me, not as in documentation*

As you can see not only `ORDER BY` but even `RANGE BETWEEN` is not allowed when `DISTINCT` is used

I think, subquery is the way to go.

In case if you need direction for this, use below simple example

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id,
  order_placed_at,
  brand_id,
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT brand) 
      FROM UNNEST(last_7_day_buyer_brands_with_dups) AS brand
  ) AS last_7_day_buyer_brands
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id,
    order_placed_at,
    brand_id,
    ARRAY_AGG(brand_id) OVER(
      PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_placed_at 
      RANGE BETWEEN 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000000 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
    ) AS last_7_day_buyer_brands_with_dups
  FROM yourTable
)
```

Comment: I wonder why this capability was dropped from legacy sql to standard sql, it was very convenient.

Comment: I was getting the following error with this example "Window framing expression must be a literal or parameter at [line_number:column_number]". I replaced this "RANGE BETWEEN 365*24*60*60 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING" with "RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING" and it worked.. seems like a bug? The documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#def_window_frame) states that numeric_preceding can be a numeric expression.. is 365*24*60*60 not a numeric expression?

Comment: For those who come across this.. I ran into a very similar problem I needed to solve but ARRAY_AGG + UNNEST was failing due to BigQuery resource constraints. @MikhailBerlyant provided an excellent answer over here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62582377/is-there-a-way-to-use-order-by-clause-in-count-aggregate-analytic-function-if-n/62583385?noredirect=1#comment110678419_62583385) that is more efficient (at least in my case)