# Is there a way to use ORDER BY clause in COUNT aggregate analytic function? If not, what is a suitable alternative?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table of orders that looks something like this:

```sql
WITH my_table_of_orders AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS order_id,
    DATE(2019, 5, 12) AS date,
    5 AS customer_id,
    TRUE AS is_from_particular_store

  UNION ALL SELECT
    2 AS order_id,
    DATE(2019, 5, 11) AS date,
    5 AS customer_id,
    TRUE AS is_from_particular_store

  UNION ALL SELECT
    3 AS order_id,
    DATE(2019, 5, 11) AS date,
    4 AS customer_id,
    FALSE AS is_from_particular_store
)
```

My actual table contains ~59 million rows.

What I would like to do is essentially return one row, per order date, with a second column that represents what percentage of customers that placed orders in the past year (relative to the current row's date), placed an order with a particular store (where my fictitious `is_from_particular_store` column comes in handy).

Ideally I could use the following query and not run into resource issues.. only problem is that you cannot use `ORDER BY` when using `DISTINCT` in an analytic function it seems, I get this `Window ORDER BY is not allowed if DISTINCT is specified`:

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store / last_year_customer_id_that_ordered AS number_i_want
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        date
    ) AS row_num,
    COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) OVER(
      ORDER BY
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))
      -- 31,536,000 = 365 days in seconds
      RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered,
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(is_from_particular_store, customer_id, NULL)) OVER(
      ORDER BY
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))
      -- 31,536,000 = 365 days in seconds
      RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store,
  FROM my_table_of_orders
)
WHERE
  -- only return one row per date
  row_num = 1
```

I then tried using `ARRAY_AGG` and `UNNEST` instead:

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  SAFE_DIVIDE((SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
    FROM UNNEST(last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store) AS customer_id
  ), (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id)
    FROM UNNEST(last_year_customer_id_that_ordered) AS customer_id
  )) AS number_i_want_to_calculate
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY
        date
    ) AS row_num,
    ARRAY_AGG(customer_id) OVER(
      ORDER BY
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))
      -- 31,536,000 = 365 days in seconds
      RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(is_from_particular_store, customer_id, NULL)) OVER(
      ORDER BY
        UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date))
      -- 31,536,000 = 365 days in seconds
      RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
    ) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store,
  FROM my_table_of_orders
)
WHERE
  -- only return one row per date
  row_num = 1
```

The only problem with this is that I get the following resource issue...

```
Resources exceeded during query execution: The query could not be executed in the allotted memory.
```

This question is incredibly similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/42567839/3902555 and suggests using `ARRAY_AGG` + `UNNEST` but like I said this causes resource issues for me :(

Anyone know of a more resource efficient way to calculate the statistic I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another totally refactored version (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE, customer_id, is_from_particular_store
  FROM my_table_of_orders
)
SELECT a.date, 
  SAFE_DIVIDE(
    COUNT(DISTINCT IF(b.is_from_particular_store, b.customer_id, NULL)),
    COUNT(DISTINCT b.customer_id)
  ) AS number_i_want_to_calculate
FROM temp a
CROSS JOIN temp b
WHERE DATE_DIFF(a.date, b.date, YEAR) < 1
GROUP BY a.date
```

Alternative to above is using [Approximate Aggregation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/approximate_aggregate_functions#approx_count_distinct) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE, customer_id, is_from_particular_store
  FROM my_table_of_orders
)
SELECT a.date, 
  SAFE_DIVIDE(
    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(IF(b.is_from_particular_store, b.customer_id, NULL)),
    APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(b.customer_id)
  ) AS number_i_want_to_calculate
FROM temp a
CROSS JOIN temp b
WHERE DATE_DIFF(a.date, b.date, YEAR) < 1
GROUP BY a.date
```

Comment: 20 minutes later it worked (your 2nd version)! I'll accept this as the accepted answer! I think in order to speed it up I'll have to try to trim down my input table in some way that is specific to my business logic..

Comment: sure. makes sense. glad it worked for you. how about very first version - is it still running? just curious :o)

Comment: I stopped it after 20 minutes but I'll give it another go and let you know

Comment: So I ended up killing it after 1h25m. Didn't complain of resource errors but I grew impatient lol

Comment: thank you for update. it still makes sense - at least you have now working version in above answer. the another one can potentially still be useful for smaller sets

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below little refactored version mostly based on first deduping customers on the same date and removing use ROW_NUMBER() which is usually heavy resource eater
Not able obviously to test on your real data , so don't know if this will be enough of further improvements still needed - so try and let us know

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DISTINCT DATE,
  SAFE_DIVIDE(
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) FROM UNNEST(last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store) AS customer_id), 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT customer_id) FROM UNNEST(last_year_customer_id_that_ordered) AS customer_id)
  ) AS number_i_want_to_calculate
FROM (
  SELECT DATE,  
    ARRAY_AGG(customer_id) OVER(win) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered,
    ARRAY_AGG(IF(is_from_particular_store, customer_id, NULL)) OVER(win) AS last_year_customer_id_that_ordered_from_a_particular_store,
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT DATE, customer_id, is_from_particular_store
    FROM my_table_of_orders
  ) 
  WINDOW win AS (ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(DATE)) RANGE BETWEEN 31536000 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually tried tagging you on this as I had seen you provided a concise answer for the other question I listed. So far your query hasn't timed out due to resource issues but it's still running after ~18 minutes lol.

Comment: Which I would think - makes sense as logic is quite heavy so let's see if it will complete or will fail again. Meantime, try another version I just added :o)